# How does RSA compute such enormous numbers?

Tags: rsa, public-key

So I have been reading and learning a lot about cryptography lately and in particular asymmetric ciphers such as RSA.

One thing that I am curious about but never seems to be mentioned is how the cipher algorithm manages to compute such enormous numbers in reasonable amounts of time.

[This example](http://doctrina.org/How-RSA-Works-With-Examples.html#a-real-world-example) shows what I mean. Such enormous numbers, and powers of enormous numbers no less. What kind of algorithm can handle computing `35052111338673026690212423937053328511880760811579981620642802346685810623109850235943049080973386241113784040794704193978215378499765413083646438784740952306932534945195080183861574225226218879827232453912820596886440377536082465681750074417459151485407445862511023472235560823053497791518928820272257787786` to the power of `89489425009274444368228545921773093919669586065884257445497854456487674839629818390934941973262879616797970608917283679875499331574161113854088813275488110588247193077582527278437906504015680623423550067240042466665654232383502922215493623289472138866445818789127946123407807725702626644091036502372545139713` in a useful amount of time?

Comment: What research have you done? This is covered in textbooks and courses on cryptography. We expect you to do a significant amount of research before asking, and to show it in the question. See http://security.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask: "Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!"

Comment: See also http://security.stackexchange.com/q/13674/971

Comment: Here's a related problem: compute the "ones" decimal digit of eleven raised to the ten billionth power. If you compute eleven to the first, second, third and fourth powers it should become rapidly pretty clear that you do not need to perform ten billion multiplications to answer that question. Now do you see why the computations in RSA are feasible?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Surprisingly, very basic algorithms which the children learn at the basic schools are used. For instance:

http://www.wikihow.com/Do-Long-Multiplication

You can find a similar algorithm for sum, sub and division. Try to ask google for: "division on paper"

The "power of" is little tricky. In cryptography you don't really need the "real power of". Instead you need:

(a ^ b) mod c

It is easy to compute a^(power of 2) mod c

```
a * a mod c= a^2 mod c
(a^2)^2 mod c= a^4 mod c
(a^4)^2 mod c= a^8 mod c
...
(a^512)^2 mod c= a^1024  mod c
```

And if you need a^5

```
(a^5) = a^2 * a^2 * a
```

thanks to "mod c" you keep the numbers no higher than c.

For example:

```
c = 10

2^2 = 4
2^4 mod 10 = (4^2) mod 10 = 16 mod 10 = 6
2^8 mod 10 = ((4^2)^2) mod 10 = (6^2) mod 10 = 36 mod 10 = 6
2^16 mod 10 = (6^2) mod 10 =....
```

etc..

There are many tricks how to make the calculation faster. For example, [Montgomery multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montgomery_modular_multiplication) algorithm is often used for that. But even without those tricks the implementation would be fast enough. I would estimate RSA instead of 0.2s would take 5s or so.

Comment: 0.2s vs 5s!?  You are _vastly_ underestimating how fast computers do math.  The difference is closer to 0.1ms vs 1ms

Comment: yah, I forgot on 486 cpu :-)

Comment: Note: If you don't do the repeated square and multiply trick you'll likely never witness the finish of your RSA signing operation...

Comment: 486 was similarly bloomin' fast.

Comment: **Montgomery multiplication does NOT make things significantly faster**, certainly not by a factor of 25: the number of elementary operations doe not change asymptotically. It does simplifies estimation of a quotient digit, and avoids the rare case when that's wrong, which is nice to have in general, and avoid a side-channel leakage.

Comment: Just note the comment about Montgomery was written by someone else. Not sure how this is possible, but it seems some people with really high reputation can modify posts of someone else. Would be nice if they remark that explicitly.

Comment: How do you perform remainder division throughout each multiplication and still get `a^e mod n`?

Comment: @smrt28 Normally the edit history would show if the post has been edited and by whom. But apparently the history has been lost due to the migration from security.se.

Answer (score 29):

There are two reasons by which such "huge" numbers can be computed in reasonable time.

The first one is that we do *not* raise one integer *x* to some big exponent *d*. What we do is that we compute *x* raised to power *d* **modulo** an integer *n*. The modulo means that we are not interested in the final integer *x*<sup>*d*</sup> but only in the remainder of the Euclidian division of *x*<sup>*d*</sup> by *n*. The good part here is that all involved numbers will reside between 0 and *n*-1; thus, they will fit in a few thousands of bits, instead of becoming (much) larger than the entire Universe.

The second reason is that the exponentiation is done through the [square-and-multiply](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) algorithm. As an example, to compute *x*<sup>100</sup> (modulo *n*), we do not do 99 multiplications by *x*; instead, we compute:

- *x*<sup>2</sup>
- (*x*<sup>2</sup>)<sup>2</sup> = *x*<sup>4</sup>
- (*x*<sup>4</sup>)<sup>2</sup> = *x*<sup>8</sup>
- (*x*<sup>8</sup>)<sup>2</sup> = *x*<sup>16</sup>
- (*x*<sup>16</sup>)<sup>2</sup> = *x*<sup>32</sup>
- (*x*<sup>32</sup>)<sup>2</sup> = *x*<sup>64</sup>
- *x*<sup>64</sup>*x*<sup>32</sup>*x*<sup>4</sup> = *x*<sup>64+32+4</sup> = *x*<sup>100</sup>

Thus a grand total of 6 squarings and 2 multiplications, i.e. way fewer than the 99 multiplications of the naive algorithm. In all generality, if the exponent fist on *k* bits (the exponent value lies between 2<sup>*k*-1</sup> and 2<sup>*k*</sup>), then the square-and-multiply algorithm will need *k*-1 squarings and at most *k*-1 multiplications (possibly much less than that with "window" optimizations).

If you want full details on such things, have a look at the [Handbook of Applied Cryptography](http://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/hac/), especially chapter 14.

Answer (score 2):

We can compute $m^e \bmod n$ using the binary exponential method.

In this method, you should first compute the binary form of $e$. Let $\ell$ be the number of bits in $e$, and let $e_i$ denote the $i$-th bit of $e$, so that $e=\sum\limits_{i=0}^\ell e_i \cdot 2^i$.

Now, with the algorithm below, you can compute $c$:

> $z:=1$
>   $\text{for } i:= \ell \text{ down to } 0 \text{ do}$
>   $\quad z:=z^2\cdot m^{e_i} \bmod n$
>   $\text{return } z$

You can do this easily in Programs such as the "MAGMA" with `Modexp(m,e,n);` in a second.